# Comparing equal datetimes returns false

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a query with how datetimes are compared/stored in C#. Consider the following code:

```
var createdDate = DateTime.Now;
using (cr = new LanguageDictionaryRepository(ds)) {
    cr.Add(new Sybrin10.Data.DTO.LanguageDictionary() {
        Active = true,
        CreatedDate = createdDate,
        CultureCode = cultureCode,
        Data = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("Test")
    });
    cr.Save();

    var y = cr.FindBy(x => x.CultureCode == cultureCode && x.CreatedDate == createdDate).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsNotNull(y);
```

The `Assert.IsNotNull` is failing because of the datetime check. I would expect that as the LanguageDictionary instance is created with the variable's value that the two would be equal. This is using Telerik.OpenAccess and MSSQL as a DB layer so I'm assuming the problem comes in there. Can anyone tell me if there is anything I'm missing with this and how to correctly compare these values.

EDIT: The tick values are different but I don't know why as they both come from the same variable which I only assign to once.

Comment: Are you sure the dates are identical? The comparison will take hours/minutes/seconds/milli-seconds into account.

Comment: That's the thing, the tick values are different but I'm not sure why as they both come from the same variable createdDate.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment accidentely :/ How much do the ticks differ? Is it a constant difference?

Comment: By 117 with x.CreatedDate being larger.

Comment: Ive updated my answer, basicly `117` difference is nothing because a Tick is one ten-millionth of a second.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's given me a lot of detail.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.Equals(x.CreatedDate, createdDate)`, it might help.

Other than that, proper `DateTime` comparing is a massively complicated subject with timezones, offsets, utc, local time and whatnot. I wouldn't at all be suprised at a simple `==` compare between two seemingly identical dates to return false.

If the `Ticks` value differs on write and read, you're might be facing a `DateTimeKind` problem, where you're writing a `DateTimeKind.Local` to the database, but getting back an `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

The other option could be (if the difference is small enough) that the `DateTime` field in your database is not significant enough to store the same amount of milliseconds as the .net `DateTime`:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

Depending on your data storage, it might not be as detailed as this. Your `DateTime` values do not come from the same source, one is read from memory, the other is read from database.

Comment: In that case, is comparing the string representation of the dates a valid option?

Comment: If you just want to get back the record you created, see Teleriks [How to: Insert Objects](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/developer-guide-crud-add.html). It will read back the created primary key after saving.

Comment: Actually I will create an extension to the DateTime class to compare without ticks as I see this coming up again. Thanks for the answer, it's given me a lot of clarity.

Answer (score 4):

SqlServer stores a [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) in (about) 3-millisecond increments.

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

A roundtrip of a DateTime through the database could thus be off by a few ms.

So you should not test for "exactly equal", but for "close enough"

```
var y = cr.FindBy(x => x.CultureCode == cultureCode && 
                        x.CreatedDate >= createdDate.AddMilliseconds(-5) && 
                        x.CreatedDate <= createdDate.AddMilliseconds(5))
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Late edit: an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsAboutEqualTo(this DateTime target, DateTime other)
        => Math.Abs((target - other).TotalMilliseconds) <= 4;
}
```

Usage

```
var y = cr.FindBy(x => x.CultureCode == cultureCode && 
           x.CreatedDate.IsAboutEqualTo(createdDate))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Do note that Entity Framework will not be able to translate this into SQL, it will only work in linq-to-objects.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks for pointing it out, i'd upvote but your code sample is not very practical in reality. now if you make it an extension, now we're talking

Comment: You can use `(x.CreatedDate - createdDate).Milliseconds < 4` if you're looking for a shorter notation.

Comment: @DdW - You will need to add a `Math.Abs` around it, because you could get negative values from that comparison (which are of course always <4)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better for you to use DateTime.UtcNow when you store the data and then you don't have to worry about daylight saving time issues etc. You can then display it how you want later using the culture you pick.